# hashCode override in Java returns null when using hashmap and getting newly created objects

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I am currently learning about Java's hashcode via MOOC and followed their tutorial. However, expected output returns null when there clearly is a value inside hashmap. My code for override is following:

```
public class Plate{
    private final String regCode;
    private final String country;

    // Counstructors
    ...

    // accessors... only showing name for less clutter
    getCode() 
    getCountry()

    @Override // toString
    public String toString(){
        return country + " " + regCode;
    }

    @Override // equals
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj == null){
            return false;
        }   

        if(getClass() != obj.getClass()){
            return false;
        }

        Plate cmp = (Plate) obj;

        if(this.country.equals(cmp.getCountry())){
            return false;
        }

        if(this.regCode == null || this.regCode.equals(cmp.getCode())){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

///////////////////////////////////// Below code may be the problem ///////////////////////////////////
    @Override // hashCode 
    public int hashCode(){
        if(this.country == null || this.regCode == null){
            return 7;
        }   

        return this.country.hashCode() + this.regCode.hashCode(); 

    }
}
```

and my main function that uses above code is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Regi{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Plate reg1 = new Plate("FI", "ABC-123");
        Plate reg2 = new Plate("FI", "UXE-465");
        Plate reg3 = new Plate("D", "B WQ-431");

        ArrayList<Plate> finnish = new ArrayList<Plate>();
        finnish.add(reg1);
        finnish.add(reg2);

        Plate newPlate = new Plate("FI", "ABC-123");
        if(!finnish.contains(newPlate)){
            finnish.add(newPlate);
        }
        System.out.println("Finnish " + finnish);


// where unexpected result occur
        HashMap<Plate, String> owners = new HashMap<Plate, String>();
        owners.put(reg1, "Arto");
        owners.put(reg3, "Jurgen");

        System.out.println("Owners:");
        System.out.println(owners.get(reg1));
        System.out.println(owners.get(new Plate("FI", "ABC-123")));
        System.out.println(owners.get(new Plate("D", "B WQ-431")));

    }
}
```

Where expected output is:

[image]

but my output displays `null` below "owners:" portion whenever I ran `System.out.println(owners.get(new Plate("FI", "ABC-123")));` and `System.out.println(owners.get(new Plate("D", "B WQ-431")));`. I'm not sure what is wrong with my custom hashCode function since I was able to print out both of my hashCode for `country` and `regCode` and they both gave numeric values. I also referenced someone else's post regarding to hashcode to use prime number but it was still displaying null. I was wondering if anyone can point me to right direction regarding to hashCode.

Comment: Just as a side note, `Jürgen` is not a very Finnish name (ah, it was for the German licence plate, that makes sense :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because you make `equals` return `false` when the two object have the **same** `country`. Or the **same** `regCode`:

```
if(this.country.equals(cmp.getCountry())){
    return false;
}

if(this.regCode == null || this.regCode.equals(cmp.getCode())){
    return false;
}
```

You're missing the `!` (NOT) operator:

```
if (! this.country.equals(cmp.getCountry())) {
    return false;
}

if (this.regCode == null || ! this.regCode.equals(cmp.getCode())) {
    return false;
}
```

Also, your `hashCode()` implementation implies that `country` can be `null`, so you're missing the null-check:

```
if (this.country == null || ! this.country.equals(cmp.getCountry())) {
    return false;
}
```